# Unable to add an extension info Firefox geckodriver

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox-addon, geckodriver

Good morning, trying to add an extension into geckodriver, which has to be initialized from .net framework, Selenium. After using

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
profile.AddExtension("foxyproxy.xpi");
options.Profile = profile;
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I get an exception: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.` (stack trace could be found on the link below)

Thats all about adding exception, because without exception everything works like a charm.

Found [this topic](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7909), but looks like it wasnt resolved.(same error as mine)

Any ideas how to fix that?